# @nrwl/angular dependency of webpack is causing vulnerability issues

Tags: angular, jenkins-pipeline, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I am using `"@nrwl/angular": "15.8.7"` version and this particular version is internally using `"webpack": "^5.75.0"`. At the time of build this is causing issue and jenkins is showing vulnerability issue and suggesting to use `"webpack": "^5.76.0",`.

I tried `overrides` in package.json but I dont see the inner dependency of `@nrwl` is getting updated. I also tried `npm-force-resolutions` with no luck. Can anyone suggest a good solution for this ?